# Finding all keys with specific name within deeply nested JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

**Overview:**

I have a huge JSON object that goes up to 40 levels deep. I need to find all keys that are exactly "videoRenderer". [Here is an example of this object](https://gist.github.com/dpw1/9cecc864dbf80ea66b1698b9c588495f).

**Issue:**

Because of its complexity I can not track down where `"videoRenderer"` will be displayed at. Therefore I can't just go by `"videos.data.videoRenderer"`. I tried looping it with `map` but it seems to take a toll on performance.

**Goal**

The end goal is to have a function like `getKeys('videoRenderer')` and it will return an array of objects with all the `"videoRenderer"`s found.

Like this: `[{"videoRenderer":{"a":1}},{"videoRenderer":{"b":2}}]`.

Kindly point me towards a direction to achieve this, I've been stuck on this for a few days now.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What would you like the output to be?  What constitutes "find" with a deeply nested JSON?

Comment: Recursive function

Comment: The output should be an array of objects. I'll update the question!

Comment: That desired output  isn't valid JS.

Comment: I apologize, it's not indeed, it was a typo. Here is the desired output that I mean: `[{"videoRenderer":{"a":1}},{"videoRenderer":{"b":2}}]`

Comment: Please provide your "deep nested JSON" structure at least with 2 levels and expected output

Comment: @PavloZhukov, [click here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dpw1/9cecc864dbf80ea66b1698b9c588495f/raw/99e8a210cb4daff5ea013b13c4632c823dbe1f17/ComplexJSON.json) for the JSON sample object. I updated the question with the desired output!

Comment: I don't see there any deep nested `videoRenderer` inside `videoRenderer`

Comment: Maybe you need to take from contents only items with key `videoRenderer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might go about it like this:

```
function allNodes(obj, key, array) {
  array = array || [];
  if ('object' === typeof obj) {
    for (let k in obj) {
      if (k === key) {
        array.push(obj[k]);
      } else {
        allNodes(obj[k], key, array);
      }
    }
  }
  return array;
}

results = allNodes(data, 'videoRenderer');
```

The `for (let k in obj)` will iterate over both object properties and array indices alike, both of which will show up as type `object`.  Then recursively ask it to push matching properties into a result array.  The example assumes your *deeply nested JSON* object is called `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Although the console is slow on Stack Overflow, I got this to work:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, html, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, aC, rC, tC, dig; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, success, context)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  x.send();
}
post = function(url, send, success, context){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('POST', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      const fd = new FormData;
      for(let k in send){
        fd.append(k, JSON.stringify(send[k]));
      }
      x.send(fd);
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; html = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
dig = function(obj, func){
  let v;
  if(obj instanceof Array){
    for(let i=0,l=obj.length; i<l; i++){
      v = obj[i]; func(v, i, obj);
      if(typeof v === 'object')dig(v, func);
    }
  }
  else{
    for(let i in obj){
      v = obj[i]; func(v, i, obj);
      if(typeof v === 'object')dig(v, func);
    }
  }
}
// here's where the magic happens
get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dpw1/9cecc864dbf80ea66b1698b9c588495f/raw/99e8a210cb4daff5ea013b13c4632c823dbe1f17/ComplexJSON.json', res=>{
  const a = [];
  dig(res, (v, i, o)=>{
    if(i === 'videoRenderer')a.push(v);
  });
  //console.log(a);
});
}); // end load
//]]>
```