# Deep search list of objects with hierarchy

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I have array of objects like this:

```
let items: MenuPath[] = [
            { title: "Archive", path: 'archive' },
            { title: "About", path: 'about' },
            { title: "Programs", path: 'programs', children: [{ title: 'Line with...', path: 'program-line' }] },
            {
                title: "Blog",
                path: 'blog',
                children: [
                    {
                        title: "Cars",
                        path: 'cars',
                        children: [
                            { title: 'Something about cars', path: 'smt-cars' },
                            {
                                title: 'Cars library',
                                path: 'cars-library',
                                children:  [
                                            { title: 'Line of horizon', path: 'line-horizon', children: [{ title: 'Something', path: 'smt-last' }] },
                                            { title: 'Lineup', path: 'lineup' },
                                        ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
```

And i need a function that will find all objects whose title contains "**line**" with full hierarchy

```
function searchAll(items, title){
 // ...
}

let result = [
   [ {title: "Programs", path: "programs"}, {title: "Line with...", path: 'program-line'} ], // path: /programs/program-line
   [ {title: "Blog", path: "blog"}, { title: "Cars", path: "cars" }, {title:"Cars library", path: "cars-library"}, {title: 'Line of horizon', path: 'line-horizon'} ], // path: /blog/cars/cars-library/line-horizon
   [ {title: "Blog", path: "blog"}, { title: "Cars", path: "cars" }, {title:"Cars library", path: "cars-library"}, {title: 'Lineup', path: 'lineup'} ], // path: /blog/cars/cars-library/lineup
];
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: `function deepSearch(array: MenuPath[], item: string) {
        let res = array.some(function s(el) {
            return (el.title.toLowerCase().includes(item.toLowerCase()) || ((el.children instanceof Array) && el.children.some(s)))
        })
        return res;
    }

let found= items.filter(i => {
        if (Array.isArray(i)) {
            return deepSearch(i, "line");
        } else {
            return deepSearch([i], "line");
        }
    })`
This finds all objects that have matches inside, but I don't know how to expand them

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include additional code since it's hard to read in comments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding all keys with specific name within deeply nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61809878/finding-all-keys-with-specific-name-within-deeply-nested-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion here, and a stack to keep track of the hierarchy.

I've also made the search take a regex, as this works well for doing searches, eg. just putting `/i` at the end allowed for a case-insenstive search.

ps: I've used structuredClone here just to make the snippet console look nicer, otherwise it create #refrences for duplicates.

```js
const items = [
    { title: "Archive", path: 'archive' },
    { title: "About", path: 'about' },
    { title: "Programs", path: 'programs', children: [{ title: 'Line with...', path: 'program-line' }] },
    {
        title: "Blog",
        path: 'blog',
        children: [
            {
                title: "Cars",
                path: 'cars',
                children: [
                    { title: 'Something about cars', path: 'smt-cars' },
                    {
                        title: 'Cars library',
                        path: 'cars-library',
                        children: [
                            { title: 'Line of horizon', path: 'line-horizon', children: [{ title: 'Something', path: 'smt-last' }] },
                            { title: 'Lineup', path: 'lineup' },
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

function searchAll(items, search){
    const stack = [];
    const results = [];
    function inner(items) {
        for (const i of items) {
            const {title, path} = i;
            stack.push({title,path})
            if (search.test(i.title))
                 results.push(structuredClone(stack));
            if (i.children) inner(i.children);
            stack.pop();
        }
    }
    inner(items);
    return results;
}
   
console.log(searchAll(items, /line/i))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```